# one-to-many relationships with django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I intend to create a teaming system, where each team may contain multiple contestants. The contestants is actually `auth.User`. Something similar to:

```
Team:  
    Contestant1
    Contestant2
    .
    .
    ContestantN
```

Since a contestant is actually a user which I cannot modify to have a foreignkey to team. What is the best way to achieve this?

The ways I though was:

- Create a `OneToOne` profile for user which points to a team.
- Define a `ManyToMany` relationship between user and team where user has to be unique.

### A Pause

I am redesigning the structure of my application, so I will rephrase the question again
Thanks for your replies, I will consider them and see if one of them fits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    contestants = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Contestant')

class Contestant(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    [here go Contestant data fields]
```

This allows one user to take part in different teams, but if you don't want to allow this, you can add **unique=True** to **Contestant.user**.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to extend the functionality of default accounts and create a new user model. The new user model can then have a foreign key to team. Like this.

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserExtended.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Now you can use the "UserExtended" in place of normal User.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `contestants` field on the `Team` model like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
contestants = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

You can't specify `unique=True` on a ManyToManyField. The good news is that it won't add the same contestant to the same team twice so you won't need to check if the contestant is unique.

Comment: but a contestant will be able to be in two team then

Comment: That's correct. My example is only making sure that a contestant isn't able to be on the same team twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to create a `Contestant` model. You'll probably end up needing to store more information about a contestant that is team-specific but separate from a player (such as whether the contestant is a starter, the contestant's number, and so on). Creating a `Contestant` model allows you to store that information separate from the `User`, and you would have a `ForeignKey` in the `Contestant` model referencing `User`s, and another `ForeignKey` in the `Contestant` model referencing `Team`s.